# How to hide overflow on a carousel slider and set a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

[Here is the fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/eaotmar3/11/)

Hi ! 
I have a carousel slider and I want to hide the overflow outside the grey box (see the fiddle) and I would like the first button (the first div inside) to come back when the last one is gone.

I am really note familiar with carousel and if someone have a basic lesson on that topic I would apreciate it. I am familiar with css but it feels like the carousel isn't working the same way. I hope this is not duplicated I didn't find a lot about carousel on stack.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.slider').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1
});
});
```

```css
#background_etape2  {
 background-color: #a6a6a6;
 width: 100%;
 height: 800px;

}

#sondage  {
 Float: left;
 left: 35px;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
 white-space: nowrap;
 position: relative;
 top: 100px;
 color: black;
}

#liste_categorie_sondage  {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto; 
 height: 200px;
    width: 600px;
 background-color: #555;
 border: 1px solid black; 
 position: relative;
 top: 390px;
}
/*
#nav_sondage {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
 list-style-position:inside;
}
*/
#categorie_sondage {
    display: block;
 width: 600px;
    color:  #99b3ff;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    list-style-position:inside;
 display: table-cell;
 font-size: 20px;
 position: relative;
 top: -300px;
 left: 250px;
 
 
}

#menusondage  {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 width: 600px;
 background-color: #808080;
 text-align: right;
 padding: 8px;
 display:table-cell;
 border: 2px solid black;
}

#menusondage:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="background_etape2" name="etape2">

 <div id="etape2"> 
   <div id="liste_categorie_sondage" class="slider">
 
   <div id="categorie_sondage"> Économie <a id="menusondage" href="economie.php">Listes des sondages</a></div>
   <div id="categorie_sondage"> Environnement <a id="menusondage" href="environnement.php">Listes des sondages</a></div>
   <div id="categorie_sondage"> Santé <a id="menusondage" href="sante.php">Listes des sondages</a></div>
   <div id="categorie_sondage"> Éducation <a id="menusondage" href="education.php">Listes des sondages</a></div>
   <div id="categorie_sondage"> Services Sociaux <a id="menusondage" href="sociaux.php">Listes des sondages</a></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT : My basic problem was coming from my link to code in the css plug-in.
Like one of the anwser told me, I need absolutely the slick.css file in order to make it work and I can or not add the -theme file. Those css sheet hide the overflow without hidding the arrow.

See those file here :

There is the first one (slick.css)

```css
/* Slider */
.slick-slider
{
    position: relative;

    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;

    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
        touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list
{
    position: relative;

    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slick-list:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-list.dragging
{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    display: block;
}
.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after
{
    display: table;

    content: '';
}
.slick-track:after
{
    clear: both;
}
.slick-loading .slick-track
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide
{
    display: none;
    float: left;

    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-slide
{
    float: right;
}
.slick-slide img
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-slide.slick-loading img
{
    display: none;
}
.slick-slide.dragging img
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
.slick-initialized .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-loading .slick-slide
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.slick-vertical .slick-slide
{
    display: block;

    height: auto;

    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

And here is the last one slick-theme.css

```css
@charset 'UTF-8';
/* Slider */
.slick-loading .slick-list
{
    background: #fff url('./ajax-loader.gif') center center no-repeat;
}

/* Icons */
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'slick';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

    src: url('./fonts/slick.eot');
    src: url('./fonts/slick.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('./fonts/slick.woff') format('woff'), url('./fonts/slick.ttf') format('truetype'), url('./fonts/slick.svg#slick') format('svg');
}
/* Arrows */
.slick-prev,
.slick-next
{
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;

    display: block;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);

    cursor: pointer;

    color: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}
.slick-prev:hover,
.slick-prev:focus,
.slick-next:hover,
.slick-next:focus
{
    color: transparent;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}
.slick-prev:hover:before,
.slick-prev:focus:before,
.slick-next:hover:before,
.slick-next:focus:before
{
    opacity: 1;
}
.slick-prev.slick-disabled:before,
.slick-next.slick-disabled:before
{
    opacity: .25;
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before
{
    font-family: 'slick';
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1;

    opacity: .75;
    color: white;

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.slick-prev
{
    left: -25px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-prev
{
    right: -25px;
    left: auto;
}
.slick-prev:before
{
    content: '←';
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-prev:before
{
    content: '→';
}

.slick-next
{
    right: -25px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-next
{
    right: auto;
    left: -25px;
}
.slick-next:before
{
    content: '→';
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-next:before
{
    content: '←';
}

/* Dots */
.slick-dotted.slick-slider
{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.slick-dots
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25px;

    display: block;

    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

    list-style: none;

    text-align: center;
}
.slick-dots li
{
    position: relative;

    display: inline-block;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 0;

    cursor: pointer;
}
.slick-dots li button
{
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;

    display: block;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;

    cursor: pointer;

    color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}
.slick-dots li button:hover,
.slick-dots li button:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-dots li button:hover:before,
.slick-dots li button:focus:before
{
    opacity: 1;
}
.slick-dots li button:before
{
    font-family: 'slick';
    font-size: 6px;
    line-height: 20px;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;

    content: '•';
    text-align: center;

    opacity: .25;
    color: black;

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.slick-dots li.slick-active button:before
{
    opacity: .75;
    color: black;
}
```

After this, I still have one probleme : The slider buttons just dont show up. 
I tried to hide my CSS code with /* */ and yes, the slider button appear but in a weird way.
[This is the picture of what happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMsxk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of issues

1. The most important is that the link to the slick CSS file is wrong. Use `//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css` (*and **add** the `-theme` file if you want to use the plugin theme*)
2. You use duplicate ids on the slides and the links inside. (*on the demo i changed those to classes*)

See updated demo

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1
});
```

```css
@import url('//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css');
@import url('//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick-theme.css');
#background_etape2 {
  background-color: #a6a6a6;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
#liste_categorie_sondage {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #555;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;
}
.categorie_sondage {
  display: block;
  color: #99b3ff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  list-style-position: inside;
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.menusondage {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: #808080;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 8px;
  display: table-cell;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.menusondage:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/851da942/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<div id="background_etape2" name="etape2">
  <div id="liste_categorie_sondage" class="slider">

    <div class="categorie_sondage">economie <a class="menusondage" href="economie.php">Listes des sondages</a>
    </div>
    <div class="categorie_sondage">environment <a class="menusondage" href="environnement.php">Listes des sondages</a>
    </div>
    <div class="categorie_sondage">health <a class="menusondage" href="sante.php">Listes des sondages</a>
    </div>
    <div class="categorie_sondage">education <a class="menusondage" href="education.php">Listes des sondages</a>
    </div>
    <div class="categorie_sondage">social<a class="menusondage" href="sociaux.php">Listes des sondages</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(*and the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/eaotmar3/14/*)

Comment: Thank for your anwser.The link is not wrong its because i downloader a file from : http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ wich contain the css.My css might not be on point, at the start, all of this was a list (nav, ul,) and i decided to try a carousel because the display wasn't so nice. I understand what you mean with the ID, I am a self learner from a to z so i never heard of that rule and I will try to use class from now on. Finally with the change to class the display seem broken in my page. I will try to work this out, could you tell me if i should keep my downloaded folder or use your link?

Comment: I think I am on a good start, I replace the ID for Class. Things are looking good but when i add overflow: hidden; the arrow on each side of the box are hidden to. My idea was to get the box larger ( exemple 700) and the div for each element inside set to a width like 600 so the arrow would be inside the box.(You dont see the arrow because your css link insn't the exact same of mine : add "-theme" juste before the .css extension of your link) Should I add an other box inside the grey box ? An other div in fact? Thanks for your help, the id and class things are really good for my knowledge.

Comment: @P-AViel the **-theme** file is to be used along the other one. So if you add both it should work as you want. (*also do not add `overflow:hidden`, that is handled by the plugin on its own*) See https://jsfiddle.net/eaotmar3/15/ on how it should be with both css files included.

Comment: @updated answer/code with the details about the plugin theme.

Comment: thank you again its very helpful. I got to apologyze, like I said I have a local copy of slick.css and -theme file and I just never look it up. I did now and I edit my post with this code. Now things are looking better in my local page I had one last problem but I where able to solve it by my own, I will update my post in case someone else get the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

To hide the overflow, add `overflow: hidden;` to `#background_etape2` in CSS.

About the circular permutation you want to achieve, it takes a bit more work to do. I'd suggest to use existing jQuery plugins which offer good solutions. Just Google 'carousel javascript' and you'll find some good and well documented examples free to download and use.

Gaby's proposal seems to be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Hiding the overflow

It is really simple just add `overflow: hidden` to the *gray box* (`#liste_categorie_sondage`)

```
#liste_categorie_sondage {
    overflow: hidden;

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    ...
}
```

But that is not the problem, you are actually not implementing the CSS provide with the plugin. More below

### Slider

Your CSS is all wrong and *missing* and if you are already using a plugin you have to include all the assets and fallow the docs.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4verick/dv5j0hou/) how it should be implemented

### Other Mistakes

You are using ID's to style your content which is a **BIG** no and *mistake*.

**ID's must be unique** it is specified ind [W3 Docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-id)

> This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.

Also they will give you a CSS specificity headache, because they are second highest (right after inline declaration)

More on CSS specificity [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)